# mysql: get result from 2 tables, regardless of a field being present in both tables

Tags: mysql, join

Quite hard to summarize my question in the title, so it's not totally covered..sorry for that :)

The problem is as follows:
I have two tables, of which one is a user table, and a second is a join table which holds a user/group combination.

I have users who can subscribe to several groups and I want to be able to check if someone is already member of a certain group. I also want to be able to get user information, regardless of the user being a member of the concerned group.

So I have:

> Table 1: userID, userName, etc...
>
> Table 2: (with unique composite index) groupID, userID

My best try is this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID
WHERE userName = 'John' AND groupID = 1
```

(to see if John is member of group 1)

I think the problem is in the `WHERE` clause. The query will only return users who are member of `groupID = 1`. But what I want is to have null returned if John is not a member of this group.

Any ideas, is this even possible? Thanks! Fab

Comment: What results do you get currently?

Comment: Is it necessary to accomplish two goals with a single query?  If not, it seems like it would be simpler to use one query for each goal.

Comment: try using `WHERE t1.userName = 'John' AND t2.groupID = 1`. Also, let us know what results you are getting.

Comment: Do you have a `GROUPS` table?

Comment: @Jam: I get no results, in my case John is no member of group 1.. and the WHERE groupID = 1 make that I get only results that meet 1.

Comment: @Matt: no, but it's more elegant and probably more efficient if there is a good solution to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the condition `table2.groupID = 1` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` conditions (otherwise the `LEFT JOIN` is cancelled):

```
SELECT u.*
     , ug.groupID 
FROM table1 AS u
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS ug 
    ON  ug.userID = u.userID 
    AND ug.groupID = 1
WHERE u.userName = 'John'
```

Another option is this approach (similar to `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT *
     , ( SELECT ug.groupID
         FROM table2 AS ug 
         WHERE ug.userID = u.userID 
           AND ug.groupID = 1
       ) AS groupID
FROM table1 AS u
WHERE userName = 'John'
```

Comment: Great ypercube, that does exactly what I was looking for! First and second... I wasn't even aware that you could extend the ON clause. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `WHERE` part to the `JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.userID = t2.userID 
    And userName = 'John' 
    AND groupID = 1
```

**edit** I generated my own data. Try this

```
With Users as
(
    Select 1 UserId, 'John' UserName
    Union Select 2, 'Tom'
),
Groups as
(
    Select 1 GroupId, 'Admin' GroupName
    Union Select 2, 'Power Users'
    Union Select 3, 'Users'
),
UserGroups as
(
    Select 1 UserId, 1 GroupId
    Union Select 2, 1
    Union Select 2, 3
)
Select *
From Groups
    Left Join (UserGroups
    Inner Join Users
        On Users.UserId = UserGroups.UserId
        And UserName = 'John'
        )
    On Groups.GroupId = UserGroups.GroupId
```

Results:

```
GroupId     GroupName   UserId      GroupId     UserId      UserName
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------
1           Admin       1           1           1           John
2           Power Users NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
3           Users       NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Although possibly optimized, this hasn't changed the resulting query.

Comment: Hi Raj, tnx for your answer... but it doesn't work. It just returns all my users :-P

Comment: Tnx Raj, I now see your answer is almost correct. Ypercube's correct answer is almost the same, the difference being he left userName = 'John' in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID
WHERE userName = 'John'
HAVING groupID = 1 OR groupID IS NULL
ORDER BY groupID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Tnx again! As far as I can see however, this still doesn't solve my answer. FYI: the answer above does what I needed.